# Show that $c_0$ is a closed subspace of $c$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, proof-verification

Denote $c_0 = \{ (\xi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}: \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\xi_n=0  \}$ and $c = \{ (\xi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}: \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\xi_n \text{ exists}\}$. Both spaces are equipped with supremum norm $\| (\xi_n)\| = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|\xi_n|.$

Question: Show that $c_0$ is a closed subspace of $c$

The question above is taken from the book 'An introductory Course in Functional Analysis' by Bower and Kalton, page $26$, exercise $2.1$.

My attempt:

I use the fact that $A$ is closed if and only if for every Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ converges to $x$, we have $x \in A.$

> Let $(\xi_n^{(i)})_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $c_0$ such that it  converges to
>    $\xi = (\xi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. We wish to show that $\xi \in c_0,$ that is,
>    $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\xi_n = 0.$     Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be
>    given.     Since $(\xi_n^{(i)})_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to
>    $\xi_n$, there exists $I$ such that $\| \xi_n^{(I)} - \xi_n
>  \|_{\infty} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$   In particular, for all $n \in
>  \mathbb{N},$ we have $|\xi_n^{(I)} - \xi_n| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$
>       Since $(\xi_n^{(i)})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $0,$ there
>    exists $N$ such that for all $n \geq N,$ we have $\| \xi_n^{(i)}
>  \|_{\infty} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$  Therefore, for $n \geq N,$ we
>    have   $$|\xi_n| \leq |\xi_n - \xi_n^{(I)}| + |\xi_n^{(I)}| \leq
>  \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon.$$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: I am using the fact that a set is closed if and only if every cauchy sequence in the set converges in the set.

Comment: ah, you are right... the notion of closure implies the convergence of $(\xi^{(i)}_n)$ in $c$ (I had forget that totally and I get confused with the notion of Cauchy completeness). So there exists such $\xi_n$ by definition regardless of the completeness of $c$, so your proof is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that the limit operator $\lim$ is a continuous functional on $c$ then $c_0=\ker \lim$ is a closed subspace.

Comment: Nice suggestion. I didn't see limit this way.

Comment: By the way, do you mind showing that limit is a bounded, hence continuous operator?

Answer (score 2):

Is correct, because you proof that the closure is in the original set