# Show that limit operator $\text{lim}:c \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous

Tags: limits, proof-verification, continuity

Denote $c = \{ \xi=(\xi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}: \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\xi_n \text{ exists} \}$ equipped with supremum norm $\| \xi \|_{\infty} = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|\xi_n|.$

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294519/show-that-c-0-is-a-closed-subspace-of-c/2294718#2294718), Daw suggested that to view limit operator $\text{lim}$ as a continuous functional on $c$. Below is my attempt to show that $\text{lim}$ is continuous.

Define $\lim: c \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $\lim(\xi) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \xi_n.$

I wish to show that $\lim$ is bounded.

Let $\xi=(\xi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in c.$ Note that

$$|\lim(\xi)| = |\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\xi_n| \leq \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|\xi_n| = \| \xi \|_{\infty}.$$

Therefore, $\| \lim \| = \sup\{ |\lim(\xi)|:\| \xi \|_{\infty} \leq 1 \} \leq 1,$ hence $\lim$ is bounded.

Since $\lim$ is both linear and bounded, it is continuous.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: looks good perhaps you could show $|\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\xi_n| \leq \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|\xi_n| $ this bound with more details

Comment: @clark: Actually I know the inequality holds intuitively, but do not know how to write down a formal proof.

Comment: Try, it is not hard.

Comment: You could say $  |\xi_n| \leq ||   \xi_n   ||_\infty  ~ \forall n$  therefore $|\lim_{n} \xi_n|    = \lim_{n} |\xi_n| \leq ||   \xi_n   ||_\infty $. which is a standard lemma.

Comment: @mirko: yes, I mean $c $

Comment: Yeah, this looks good.